# Remove expo from react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I've had so many troubles with the tool, I seriously have been debugging expo morethan the app itself.

How might I remove expo completely from CRNA? I would like to use CRNA and it's debugging  tools without expo

Answer (score 8):

You can do it by ejecting your app running **npm run eject**

Then, if you have any reference to expo just remove all of them.

your app modules before being ejected looks like this below:

[image]

When you run **npm run eject** it will ask some questions like:

[image]

be sure to select React Native: I'd like a regular react Native project

And your folders will now look like this (no expo):

[image]

Just be careful because ejecting is a permanent process, you should make a backup of your files.

Comment: Would you illustrate please ?

Comment: Sure, when you eject your CRNA you turn it into a react native app like if you created the app running the react-native command, so it will create the android and ios folders and get ride of expo.  You can refer to this part in the [documentation](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app#npm-run-eject)

Answer (score 6):

Once you eject from Expo, though, and if you're using a Windows computer, you'll only be able to develop for Android, I believe.  You'll still need a Mac to work in React Native without Expo.  I'm a beginner but just wanted to highlight this difficulty faced by Windows users when ejecting from Expo.